# Issue with merge and delete javabeans

Tags: java, merge, entity, javabeans

Good evening , I'm trying to remove and update entity stored into a datatable,the application doesen't give me errors but de facto it doesen't merge and remove the record from the db

May be the problem is in the entitymanager

Someone could explain me what's i'm doing wrong?

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" icon="pi pi-check" action="#{marcaController.creaMarca()}"
                                 update="manage-product-content" process="manage-product-content @this"/>
//...
 <p:commandButton value="Yes" icon="pi pi-check" action="#{marcaController.deleteMarca()}"
                             process="@this" oncomplete="PF('deleteProductDialog').hide()"/>
```

This is  MarcaController

```
    Marca m=new Marca();
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EJB
    private MarcaDao marcaDao;

    
    public void openNew() {
        this.m = new Marca();
    }
    
    public Marca getSelected() {
        return m;
        
    }
    public void setSelected(Marca m) {
        this.m=m;
    }
    public void creaMarca() {
        
       if(m.getIdmarca()==null) {
            try {
                marcaDao.create(m);
                FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage
                        (FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Product created"
                                ,"OK");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Success", m);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage
                        (FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage()
                                ,"KO");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Error", m);
                
                
            }
       }
       else {
        
           update();
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Product Updated"));
       }
    
        PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('manageProductDialog').hide()");
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form:messages", "form:dt-products");
        
    }
    public void update() {
        
        marcaDao.update(getSelected());
        
    }
    public  void deleteMarca() {
        Marca m1=m;
        
        marcaDao.deleteById(m1.getIdmarca());
        
        m=null;
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Product Removed"));
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form:messages", "form:dt-products");
        
    }
```

This is   MarcaDao

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "mio-persistence-unit")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void create(Marca entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
    }

    public void deleteById(Integer id) {
        
        Marca entity = em.find(Marca.class, id);
        if (entity != null) {
            em.remove(entity);
        }
    }


    public void update(Marca entity) {
        
        Marca m2 = em.find(Marca.class, entity.getIdmarca());
        
        em.merge(m2);
        
    }
```

Thank you in advance!